# Sql Select Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a problem in my sql query.

My code is:

```
  $sSQL = "SELECT * FROM sub_admin WHERE UserName ='".$user."' , 
  Password = '".$pass."' AND Branch='it'";
```

But it shows this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Password = 'ss' AND     
Branch='it'' at line 1
```

I assign the username and password to the two columns, but want to match the branch to database table data which is already inserted into it.

the code which i used to fetch the data contain the following query but it will not working also...

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conn.php';
include 'layouts/header.php';
$sql="SELECT * FROM signup where Department='it'";
if($sql)
{
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
else
{
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM signup WHERE Department='management'";
    $resul=mysql_query($sql2);
}

?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="navigation" >
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="selected_user.php">Users Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="message.php">Post New Anousment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="page">

            <h2>Admin Menu</h2>
            <p>Welcome to Admin Area</p>
<div class="tbl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>FirstName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>LastName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>UserName</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Department</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>ID#</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Phone #</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Status</strong></th>
                </tr>
<?php  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['First_Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Last_Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Username'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Department']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Employe_Id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Status']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
            </table>
</div>
        </div>
        </div>






<?php include 'layouts/footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: Major SQL injection vulnerability. Do not create queries by concatenating strings, especially if the strings come from the user. Use mysqli or, better, PDO, and make use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` clauses do not use commas.  I think you want `and`:

```
WHERE UserName ='".$user."' AND Password = '".$pass."' AND Branch='it'
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?  This appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe for encouraging code that's vulnerable to SQL injection instead of mentioning bound parameters? Or possibly for answering a question that probably should be closed under the 'offtopic/typo' category.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Nevertheless, it still answers the question. Have tried answering the question mentioning the bound parameters in your comment? The answer doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Just guessing on why it might have been.

Comment: Then *I guess* whoever downvoted this will read my comment.:)

Comment: @ChristianMark: I see lot of downvote practice under `php` tag on postings that do not suggest to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: @Ravinder, Yes I understand, but they usually care to comment the reason.:) They don't *just* downvote.

Comment: @AndrewMedico . . . If it is of interest, when I answered the question, it was neither tagged as php, had only a one line snipped of code, and the question was explicitly about SQL.  The question has been edited since then, but you can see the edit history by clicking on "edited".

Answer (score -2):

Copy/Paste and check this:

```
$sSQL = "SELECT * FROM `sub_admin` WHERE `UserName` ='".$user."' and `Password` = '".$pass."' AND `Branch`='it'";
```

Comment: 'Do this' is not a good answer. You should have some explanation of *why* your answer fixes the problem.

Comment: You're right. So of course missing "AND" parameter was a problem (as #Gordon Linoff mentioned). Second suggestion - always put columns name in apostrophes. Third one - are the variables safe to pass to DB? You can consifer using mysql_real_escape_string($your_variable) to avoid mysql injections.

Comment: @marcineck "apostrophe" != "backtick".

Comment: why the two queries are not working?